# Node.js class issue, or Am I doing something wrong?

Tags: node.js, coffeescript

this code

```
class Foo
  bar: []

test = new Foo()
test.bar.push('b')

test2 = new Foo()
console.log test2.bar
```

Will produce output `['b']`. How it is even possible?

## Edit:

This is what CoffeScript generates:

```
// Generated by CoffeeScript 1.4.0
var Test, test, test2;

Test = (function() {
  function Test() {}
  Test.prototype.a = [];
  return Test;
})();

test = new Test();
test.a.push('b');

test2 = new Test();
console.log(test2.a);
```

And therefore is exactly true what is written below. Thank you guys.

Comment: What language are you writing?

Comment: If `bar` is defined on the prototype, then this is possible.

Comment: @SLaks That appears to be coffeescript

Comment: I think you made it a 'class' variable.

Comment: Sorry, yes this is coffeescript

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`bar` is a single array instance that belongs to `Foo.prototype`.
`new Foo().bar` will always refer to this *same* array instance.

Therefore, any mutations performed through one `Foo` instance will also be visible thtough any other `Foo` instance.

The solution:

### Never put mutable state in a prototype.

Comment: "Never put mutable state in a prototype." - rightfully bolded. I got bitten by that when I was less experienced. :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want `Foo`'s to be created with `this.bar = []`, do it in the constructor:

```
class Foo
  constructor: -> @bar = []
```

Comment: Yeah, this is how I am doing it now. My fault. CoffeeScript confused me - in the moment I saw generated code, it was clear to me. Thank you.